# DoFixture error: Trying to follow fitSharp tutorial

Tags: c#, tdd, fitnesse, fitsharp

I'm trying to follow along in the free ebook "Test Driven .NET Development With FitNesse: Second Edition" from http://gojko.net/fitnesse/book/

The HelloWorld example works great, but 2nd example (page 41) always fails with an error of:

`fitSharp.Machine.Exception.TypeMissingException: Type 'DoFixture' not found in assemblies`

For the life of me, I can't figure out what is different that will make the 2nd example fail.

Using VS2005

Can anyone confirm/help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OK, my error.**

For the record: I forgot to make the fixture class public.

I do wish there was better error tracing/debugging.

A "debug at error" link would have solved this in an instant.  Sigh.

Comment: That misleading error message is being fixed in the upcoming release.